# Facing errors with contract invocation ( Unable to access a function stating only owner can access it , even tho I am the owner)

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-invocation, chainlink, chainlink-vrf

(sorry for structuring the question in a wrong way as I am not sure what term to use precisely) I am facing issue while trying to call the function flip in the program below ,  I am using chainlinks VRF to get a random number , I am not sure why wont it allow me to access it . Error :- It keeps saying that only the owner can access it( but only the owner is trying to access the function).This is on Sepolia network , the vrf contract address is also mentioned.

````
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

interface vrfConsumer{
    function requestRandomWords() external returns(uint256 rqeuestId);

    function getRequestStatus(uint256 _requestId) external view returns (bool fulfilled, uint256[] memory randomWords);
  
}

contract CoinFlip {

    event ChoicePlayer(uint256 requestId);
    // event NumOfWords(uint256[] numberofwords);

    uint256 public constant fee = 1000000000000000;
    address private vrfcontract = 0x4b5426E170ab3909E39Fc2f374E017BaAc0eAA86; 
    uint256 public requestId;
    address private owner;

    enum choice{
        HEADS,
        TAILS
    }

    struct coinflipStatus{
        choice player;
        uint256 requestId;
        uint256[]  numofWords;
        bool fullfilled;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => coinflipStatus) public playerStatus;

    constructor () {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier  amountPaid(uint256 value){
        require(value == fee,"Did not pay enough!");
        _;
    }

    modifier  onlyOwner(){
        require(owner == msg.sender,"Only called by owner!");
        _;
    }

    function flip() public  onlyOwner    {
        uint256 _requestedId = vrfConsumer(vrfcontract).requestRandomWords();



        // coinflipStatus memory coinstatus;
        // coinstatus.player = value;
        // coinstatus.requestId = _requestedId;
        
        // playerStatus[_requestedId] = coinstatus;
        requestId = _requestedId;
        emit ChoicePlayer(_requestedId);

    }


    // function getStatus() public  returns(uint256[] memory numsWords){
    //     coinflipStatus memory coin;
    //     coin = playerStatus[requestId];
    //     (bool result , uint256[] memory numofwords) = vrfConsumer(0x4b5426E170ab3909E39Fc2f374E017BaAc0eAA86).getRequestStatus(coin.requestId);
    //     if(result == true){
    //         coin.numofWords = numofwords;
    //         coin.fullfilled = true;
    //         emit NumOfWords(numofwords);
    //         return(numofwords); 
    //     }
    // }

    

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Well I found an Answer, VRF Contract provided by chainlin  the requestNumberofwords function can only be called by the owner. So just remove the onlyOwner modifier .